# The best database class or functions for PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm going to start to write a new software with PHP, and I need to know the best way to use database. Should I choose a database class such as Adodb, ezSql etc.

What do you think **which class is the best one?**

Comment: Are you wondering whether to use an Object-Relational Mapper like Doctrine? Or are you simply wondering which Database-Access wrapper is the best?

Comment: @Noah: Eventually, I decided to write it from scratch using ORM. They are not good enough for my project even Zend_db..

Answer (score 4):

It depends if you need an ORM, or just a database abstraction layer. If you're using `Zend Framework` then `Zend_Db` is a great choice. [Propel ORM](http://www.propelorm.org) is a great ORM for PHP. [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) is another great ORM library. On the other hand if you only need an abstraction layer, consider using the built-in PDO, or libraries like [PEAR MDB2](http://pear.php.net/package/MDB2).

Answer (score 3):

The simplest and lightweight db class is

http://code.google.com/p/edb-php-class/

```
<?php
$result = $db->q("select * from `users`limit 3");

foreach($result as $a){
        $a = (object) $a;
        echo $a->id.' '.$a->name.' '.$a->url.' '.$a->img.'</br>';
}


$result = $db->line("select * from `users` where id = '300' limit 1");
echo $result['name']; 
echo $result['surname']; 



$name = $db->one("select name from `ilike_pics` where id = '300' limit 1");
echo $name;
?>
```

Comment: I like your examples, all these answers need a few examples like this.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using PHP's PDO (PHP Data Objects) extension alongside a light-weight database class that extends PDO. You can find this open-source project on Google's Project Hosting at http://code.google.com/p/php-pdo-wrapper-class.

Answer (score 1):

[ADOdb](http://adodb.sourceforge.net/). Fast, easy to implement, well documented (not as in read the code to understand) and does nothing you do not want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to ADOdb:

https://open-mv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/

Not much documentation tough at the moment.